# Combine Maximum in Array

Tags: arrays, max

Given an array **A** of integers, of size **N**.
One can select any two adjacent indices, say **i** and **i+1**.

**Operation:** If A[i] == A[i+1], then you can remove A[i] and A[i+1], and put a single number in
their place with value A[i]+1.

Maximize the maximum possible value left in the array after performing the above operation 0 or more times.

Example:
A = 1, 2, 2, 3

After 1st operation -> 1 3 3

After 2nd operation -> 1 4

return **4**

I couldn't come up with an optimized algorithm. I could think of the only Divide and Conquer approach.

Comment: Hi. You have incorrectly tagged this with Combine. Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java. I came out with a solution but not performant like Collections.max, but I respected your algorithm:

```
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3));
    boolean repeat = true;
    while (repeat) {
        repeat = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (a.get(i).equals(a.get(i + 1))) {
                a.set(i, a.get(i) + 1);
                a.remove(i + 1);
                repeat = true;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a.get(a.size() - 1));
```

Comment: It seems that you have just iterated from left to right. What if the array is,
A[] = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6};
According to your algorithm, you will return 6.
5, 5, 4, 6
6, 4, 6

But the correct solution is 7 as below.
4, 5, 5, 6
4, 6, 6
4, 7